# Compare array against array column in postgres

Tags: postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

```
#  things               :string           is an Array

scope :things, ->(q) { where('ARRAY[?]::varchar[] IN things', Array.wrap(q)) }

scope :things, ->(q) { where('things && ARRAY[?]::varchar[]', Array.wrap(q)) }

scope :things, ->(q) { where('ARRAY[?]::varchar[] <@ things', Array.wrap(q)) }
```

I've tried a few versions, but I can't seem to find the proper incantation. I'm looking to find any row that has any of the things in the array... is there any overlap?

```
[1, 2, 3] & [1, 8] = t
[1, 2, 3] & [8, 9] = f
```

I'm trying to mimic ActiveRecord's default `where` behavior. If I give it an array, it'll get all the matching rows. Is this possible with postgres arrays? Is it even efficient?

Comment: `&&` is the "overlaps" operator for arrays so the second one should work. What do the `things` values look like? What does `q` look like? What does `Model.things(q).to_sql` look like with the second version of the scope?

Comment: `&&` does work! My sample data was wrong, so I was getting `[]` correctly, but thinking it was incorrect. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing this is by converting the arrays to a set of rows. Once you have the arrays as set of rows, you can do an intersection between them and check if the result is empty set.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE my_test_table(id BIGINT, test_array BIGINT[]);
INSERT INTO my_test_table(id, test_array)
  VALUES
  (1, array[1,2,3]),
    (2, ARRAY[1,5,8]);

SELECT * FROM my_test_table
 WHERE  array_length((SELECT array
    (
        SELECT UNNEST(test_array)
        INTERSECT
        SELECT UNNEST(array[3,15,2])
    )), 1) > 0;
```

The result of the `SELECT` statement above is:

```
1 | {1,2,3}
```

This allows for more complex matching of elements of 2 arrays. For example, if you would like to select the arrays that have at least 2 common elements, you could just change the `WHERE` part to

```
 WHERE  array_length((SELECT array
    (
        SELECT UNNEST(test_array)
        INTERSECT
        SELECT UNNEST(array[3,15,2])
    )), 1) > 1;
```

Comment: But [`array && array`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-OPERATORS-TABLE) already does this.

Comment: Yes, but the `&&` operator on array returns a `boolean` result. So you can never know how many matches you had between the arrays. The method I explained above (the last paragraph) shows how you can do more complex checks like: at least N overlapping elements, exactly N overalapping elements and etc.
Anyway, I agree that the && operator should work for the OP.

Comment: ty @DimitarSpasovski